# Settings to access printer 'PRINTERNAMEHERE' are not valid

Tags: c#, api, service, printing

So i have been trying to print out files from an asp.net API that I run as a service.

When I don't run it as a Service it works fine but as soon as I run it as a Service it doesn't do anything and Logs. `Settings to access printer 'PRINTERNAMEHERE' are not valid`

I have tried to change up some files in the registry as explained [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/184291/com-objects-fail-to-print-when-called-from-asp).

Answer (score 0):

The thing that fixed it for me was changing the user from the services itself from `Local System` to the administrator account